# GET API Call from Ansible using Jquery (jmespath)

Tags: jquery, python, json, api, ansible

Jquery in Ansible is not working well for me. Here is the scenario.

I am trying to make GET call to satellite api. It brings me the following output:

```
"parameters": [
            {
                "name": "sports", 
                "value": "soccer"
            }, 
            {
                "name": "color", 
                "value": "blue"
            }, 
        ],
```

Now I want to grep the value of sports. here is my playbook

```
- name: Make GET api calls from ansible
  uri:
    url: https://example/api/xyz
    method: GET
    user: administrator
    password: space@L42
    force_basic_auth: yes
    validate_certs: no
  register: getoutput
- name: grep the value of sports
  debug: msg="{{ getoutput.json|json_query('parameters[?name=='sports'].value') }}"
```

It is throwing error for question mark..

> `FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected char u'?'

i am following documentation here
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter 
http://jmespath.org/tutorial.html ----Filter Projections section

On the other side if i replace the debug line with the line mentioned below. it works but it displays it via array and i don't want to grep anything with array ID.

```
debug: msg="{{ getoutput.json|json_query('parameters[0].value') }}"
```

Can any one of you please help please .

Comment: Explain the meaning of each quotation mark to your rubber duck. Then apply the mechanism shown in the Ansible documentation which you linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the doc page which you linked to, there is an example:

> ```
> - name: "Display all server names from cluster1"
>   debug: var=item
>   with_items: "{{domain_definition|json_query(server_name_cluster1_query)}}"
>   vars:
>     server_name_cluster1_query: "domain.server[?cluster=='cluster1'].port"
> ```

Why does it define `server_name_cluster1_query` variable only to use it two lines above, instead of including `"domain.server[?cluster=='cluster1'].port"` directly in the `with_items`?

Because the whole template in `with_items` must be quoted, the query must be quoted and the string `cluster1` must also be quoted.

There are single and double quotes, but no triple quotes.

---

Let's look at your example:

> ```
> msg="{{ getoutput.json|json_query('parameters[?name=='sports'].value') }}"
> ```

You have two strings in single quotes: `parameters[?name==` and `].value`.

And three parts in double quotes: `{{ getoutput.json|json_query(`, `sports`, and `) }}`.

They don't make sense together, right?

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. ! you are a  life saver. you are awesome :)

Comment: Upon @techraf suggestion, I added the quotes and it worked. :) Here is the line which i replaced  debug: msg="{{ restdata.json|json_query("parameters[?name=='sssd_user'].value") }}"